# How to increase the height of my background image and position Button

Tags: html, css

```
      <div class = "LeftMain" >

              <a href = "#" > <button>Go</button></a>



      </div>


.LeftMain{

    float: left;
    width: 600px;
 }



.LeftMain {
    background: url(Astronaut.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I'm creating a mini project, and I am trying to create a button appear in front of a background image, this doesn't really work as it only displays a bit of the top part of the background image along with the button "Go". I  have floated the section as its two parts but I'm just talking about the left side for now. So how can I make the full background image appear with the button in the centre of the background image?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://www.indiacrunch.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Astronaut-in-India.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.container button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes like that but I have already created a container div you see , I created a small section in the container to have a different background pic with a button in the centre.

Comment: So, whats the problem? If you only see small background, it's because your section (button parent) don't have enough height. Its depend on button height. Try to add `height` to your `. LeftMain`.